# Get height of CustomView in xml constructor

Tags: android, xml, constructor, height, android-custom-view

I have a Custom Relative Layout that generates automatically some Frame Layouts.Each Frame Layout have a Height and Margin-Top that depends on the height of my CustomView. If i try to get that from the constructor i receive null as answer. I have tried with `getHeight()` and with `getMeasuredHeight()` but it doesn't work. I can get it overriding the `onMeasure()` or `onLayout()` methods but than i can't use the value that i get because this 2 methods are called after the constructor.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<com.cviing.cviing.FolderStackLayout

    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:id="@+id/activity_cv2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.cviing.cviing.CV2"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">


</com.cviing.cviing.FolderStackLayout>
```

Class:

```
public class FolderStackLayout extends RelativeLayout {
  int gap = 10;
  int foldersNumber = 10;
  Context context;
  int height;
  private int position;
  int baseTop;


public FolderStackLayout(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init(context, null, 0);
}

public FolderStackLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init(context, attrs, 0);

}

public FolderStackLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    init(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);

}


public void init (Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr){
    this.context = context;
    createView();

}

@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed,
                        int left,
                        int top,
                        int right,
                        int bottom) {
    int height = getMeasuredHeight();
    if (height > 0) {
        baseTop = height / getCount() - gap;
    }
}

public int getCount(){
    return foldersNumber;
}



public int getPosition() {
    return position;
}
public void createView(){
}
}
```

How can i do?

Answer (score 0):

The height is not known at the time the `View` is being constructed. For example, suppose that I have:

```
void foo() {
  new FolderStackLayout();
}
```

Clearly, that `FolderStackLayout` will not have a height. It is a Java object, nothing more. Widgets and containers only get measured and laid out sometime after they are added to some parent, and that will long after the constructor has returned.

Whatever work you are doing based on this needs to move elsewhere, such as the `onMeasure()`  or `onLayout()` that you mentioned.

Comment: I don't create an object. I Have created it on the xml file and have specified that his height is MATCH_PARENT.

Comment: @FabioPiunti: That does not matter.

Comment: I can't add childs from onMeasure(). onLayout() or onDraw(). This mhetods are called often and it is not convenient

Comment: So what can i do? Create a class like an adapter for add the view that i need?

Comment: @FabioPiunti: I have no idea, as I do not know what `FolderStackLayout` is supposed to be. You might take a look at existing open source container classes that are reminiscent of what you are trying to do, then see how they do it.